# How to determine Application Insights instance from connection string?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have an Application Insights connection string, and want to find my way to the instance in Azure Portal so that I can view logs from my app running with that connection string. We have many instances of Application Insights across several Subscriptions, across a couple Accounts, which means I can't just click into each of them and check the connection string for a match.

The connection string looks like `InstrumentationKey=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000;IngestionEndpoint=https://southcentralus.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/`

There's a URL, but that's generic for all instances in the region. Only thing that's unique is the InstrumentationKey.

I tried logging into the Portal and entering the InstrumentationKey into the search box, no hits on any Account.

Am I out of luck?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it via a Resource Graph Query, for example in Azure CLI

```
az graph query -q "Resources | where type =~ 'Microsoft.Insights/components' | where properties['ConnectionString'] == 'InstrumentationKey=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000;IngestionEndpoint=https://southcentralus.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/' | project id, resourceGroup, name"
```

//edit: As suggested in the comments by ZakiMa, a more robust way would be to check against the Instrumentation Key property:

```
az graph query -q "Resources | where type =~ 'Microsoft.Insights/components' | where 'InstrumentationKey=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000;IngestionEndpoint=https://southcentralus.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/' contains properties['InstrumentationKey'] | project id, resourceGroup, name"
```

Comment: Perfect! .. and adding Resource Graph to the to study list.

Comment: Connection strings might change over time (for instance, new endpoint can be added). The more streamlined way is to do this query against "instrumentationkey" property (and grab it from connection string).

Comment: good point @ZakiMa I added that to my answer